# Retrieve the job result from HDFS

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

to read the file directly from HDFS without copying it to the local file system. i copied the results to the local file system though.

hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ mkdir /tmp/gutenberg-output
bin/hadoop dfs -getmerge /user/hduser/gutenberg-output /tmp/gutenberg-output
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

20/11/17 21:58:02 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
the linux answer is
getmerge: `/tmp/gutenberg-output': Is a directory
how to fix the error please?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try to output this particular HDFS directory itself instead of the contents inside of it.

The good thing about the HDFS, though, is that it does follow a couple of Unix-based command line conventions, so you can really read the contents of a file under this directory (which you supposedly have the output of a job) by using the `cat` command like this:

```
hadoop fs -cat output_directory/part-r-00000
```

Where the `output_directory` is the name of the directory your desired output is stored and the `part-r-00000` is the name of the file (or the first of a set of files named `part-r-00000`, `part-r-00001`, etc. depending on the number of your job's reducers that you might define) with the results of the job.

If the above command throws an error that there's no such file with that name, then either your job has stumbled upon a problem before setting the output `key-value` pairs, or your version of Hadoop is a bit older and the name of the output file(s) is something like `part-00000`, `part-00001` and it goes on.

As an example of the, the following output in the screenshot below is from an executed job where its output was stored under the `wc_out` directory in the HDFS:

[image]